# Sort custom listview extended ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom dynamic listview and at the top of the page, I have a button who can add an item to listview infinitely like this:

**Code**

```
 btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            note = new StructNote();
            note.title = " edit your title ";
            note.description = "";
            G.notes.add(note);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

> 1- how i can sort this listview (the last created item to first
>   created item)
>
> 2- how i can set a button in my first page so the user can open the
>   last opened item of listview from first page (for shortcut).

here is my **adapter note**:

```
public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

    public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
    }

    static Typeface myfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(G.context.getAssets(), "homa.ttf");


    private static class ViewHolder {

        public Button      btnedit;
        public ViewGroup   layoutRoot;
        public TextView    txtTitle;
        public TextView    txtDescription;
        public ImageView   imgDelete;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio);

            btnedit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnedit);
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            layoutRoot = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutRoot);
            imgDelete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
        }


        public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<StructNote> adapter, final StructNote item, final int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(item.title);
            txtDescription.setText(item.description);
            txtTitle.setTypeface(myfont);
            txtDescription.setTypeface(myfont);
            btnedit.setTypeface(myfont);
            adapter.getItem(position);
            G.selectedItemPositon = position;

            imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    adapter.remove(item);

                }
            });

            btnedit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, ActivityEdit.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                    G.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, CounterActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                    G.selectedItemPositon = position;
                    G.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        StructNote item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.fill(this, item, position);

        return convertView;

    }
```

}

**G class**

```
public class G extends Application {

    public static Context               context;
    public static LayoutInflater        inflater;
    public static Activity              currentActivity;
    public static ArrayList<StructNote> notes = new ArrayList<StructNote>();
    public static SharedPreferences     preferences;
    public static int                   selectedItemPositon;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
}
```

And here is **my button on first page** :

```
 btnlastz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (G.notes.size() == 0) {

                Intent ii = new Intent(Firstpage.this, ActivityMain.class);
                Firstpage.this.startActivity(ii);

            } else {
                Intent zz = new Intent(Firstpage.this, CounterActivity.class);

                zz.putExtra("position", ActivityMain.note.Turn);

                Firstpage.this.startActivity(zz);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: here is my StructNote: public class StructNote {

    public String title;
    public String description;}

Comment: For sorting use a int variable in your StructNote class and assign sequential value then sort using comparator. Then for last opened position use position varible in activity class .Then always set this from your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- how i can sort this listview (the last created item to first
>   created item)

Here is a simple example

```
List items = new ArrayList();
//some fictitious objectList where we're populating data
for(Object obj : objectList) {
// THE KEY IS TO ADD THE ITEM AT POITIN 0

    items.add(0, obj);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
//THIS WILL REFRESH THE LISTVIEW
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
}
```

> 2- how i can set a button in my first page so the user can open the
>   last opened item of listview from first page (for shortcut).

To achieve this you need to save the position of last opened item and then get the position from that button click. and to make the process easy i would suggest you to use [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo), my personal favorite, its fast and easy,

Example: include the class in your project and then

```
 // Save the position of item clicked here
layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //JUST TWO LINES
    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(mContext);
    tinydb.putInt("position", position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, CounterActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
    G.selectedItemPositon = position;
    G.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
```

and then on button click

```
    int position;
    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(mContext);
    tinydb.getInt("position", position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, CounterActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do smoothScrollToPosition, after notifyDataSetChanged you will see the listview from the start
and for saving the position of the last clicked item you can save this sharePrefs without using any libs or sqlite, or use a global variable in application class

Comment: sometimes lists are longer so I included to make sure it gets to top. and for second question [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) is not lib its just a simple tiny class, and I gave him this option because i thot he might want to enable user to resume after application restart.

Comment: thank you guys, someone out of this website helped me 2days after i asked the question.